# Replace a numeric value in sql with new value

Tags: mysql

I have multiple values like below :

```
1.212302157,305027504,302002744
2.305027504,302002744,212302157
```

I want to remove 212302157 and add 212605226.

What will be the single line update query for the same .

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If you are storing multiple values as a comma separated string in a single field, then this is really a bad practice. Try to normalize the schema of your table.

Comment: Anyway, you can use `REPLACE` to do what you want.

Comment: Does nobody read the manuals these days?

Answer (score 0):

I think It's not the best way..
but my ans for this question is

syntax :

```
 update Table_name set c_name = concat( 
    Replace( 
       Replace( c_name, concat('RemovedStr',','), '' ), 
        concat(',' ,'RemovedStr'), '' 
    ), 
   'AddedStr' 
) [where condition];
```

u r query according to me:

```
update Table_name set c_name=concat(Replace(Replace(c_name,concat('212302157',','),''),concat(',','212302157'),''),'212605226');
```